# Make - No rule to make target - for ARM assembler file

Tags: assembly, makefile, arm

I try to compile include math functions from CMSIS

https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__RealFFT.html#ga5d2ec62f3e35575eba467d09ddcd98b5

the problem is that there is an assembler file that does not get compiled and I don't know how to make it build with the MAKEFILE

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/arm_bitreversal2.o', needed by 'build/MyProject.elf'.  Stop.
```

here is my makefile

```
# Project Name
TARGET = MyProject

# Sources
CPP_SOURCES = MyProject.cpp 

# Library Locations
LIBDAISY_DIR = ../DaisyExamples/libDaisy
DAISYSP_DIR = ../DaisyExamples/DaisySP

ASM_SOURCES = \
$(LIBDAISY_DIR)/Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_bitreversal2.s

C_SOURCES = \
$(LIBDAISY_DIR)/Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_rfft_fast_f32.c \
$(LIBDAISY_DIR)/Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_rfft_fast_init_f32.c \
$(LIBDAISY_DIR)/Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Source/CommonTables/arm_common_tables.c \
$(LIBDAISY_DIR)/Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Source/CommonTables/arm_const_structs.c \
$(LIBDAISY_DIR)/Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_cfft_f32.c \
$(LIBDAISY_DIR)/Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_bitreversal.c \
$(LIBDAISY_DIR)/Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_cfft_radix8_f32.c
C_INCLUDES += \
-I$(LIBDAISY_DIR)/Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Include 

# Core location, and generic makefile.
SYSTEM_FILES_DIR = $(LIBDAISY_DIR)/core
include $(SYSTEM_FILES_DIR)/Makefile
```

please help me on this one

let me know if you need more informations

Comment: GNU make's documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) says there are built-in rules for both `.s` and `.S` files, presumably to make `.o` files from them.

Comment: Your output directory seems to be `build/`, and your input directory is does not match that.   So either the included makefile is using `vpath` or you're not using implicit rules.   Check `$(SYSTEM_FILES_DIR)/Makefile` to see if it has defined pattern rules, and if so, if there's one for `.s` files (also note, that `.S` and `.s` typically imply different things -- typically assembly source files are in `.S`, whereas `.s` are typically intermediate files.  `ASM_SOURCES` should likely, in my opinion, have capital `.S` extensions...)

Comment: sorry, but what does not match? I launch the make command in the root of the project, it wont work in build directory. besides the .c files compile, and indeed .s or .S should be treated as assembly compilation. I don't understand why this error

Comment: I just renamed the file to .s and voilà